# Save local file from MS SQL varbinary

Tags: vb.net, uipath

I'm trying to save a local document stored in SQL db using UiPath.
From the `execute query` activity it returns a `DataTable` value with one column(“Data”).

If I'm not wrong somehow I need to transform the `DataTable.rows(0)(“Data”)` (studio is interpreting it as `object`) to an array of bytes.

I used invoke code but the file is broken:

```
Dim _MemoryStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
Dim _BinaryFormatter As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()
_BinaryFormatter.Serialize(_MemoryStream, inputObj)
_MemoryStream.ToArray()

File.WriteAllBytes(“C:\Users\Desktop\test.tiff”, _MemoryStream.ToArray())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you serialised an object when saving, which I doubt, there's no reason to try to deserialise an object when retrieving. Every field from a `DataRow` is returned as an `Object` reference, because it must support any type of object, but that object still has its own type. If you saved binary data then that type will be `Byte()`, i.e. a `Byte` array. Kinda looks like `File.WriteAllBytes` takes a `Byte` array:

```vb
File.WriteAllBytes(“C:\Users\Desktop\test.tiff”, DirectCast(inputObj, Byte()))
```

That is what I would expect that you need to do. It does depend on how you saved the data in the first place but if you used `File.ReadAllBytes` or `Image.Save` then this should do the job. If not, show us how you sabed the data in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! (The original object is an array of bytes already - varbinery data type in mssql). i found out that it's actually a zip arhive...